# how to manipulate the line-visiting history in emacs?

Tags: emacs, ide

in **eclipse**, there is a shortcut *Alt-LeftArrow* to jump to the last line visited. i wonder whether there are similar functions in emacs's coding tools, for example **cedet**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can jump to last visited lines in the current file by calling `C-u C-SPACE`.

You can call this command repeatedly so you will visit all lines in mark ring.

Actually, emacs keeps two mark rings - local and global. To jump to the latest mark in the global ring call `C-x C-SPACE`. And you can do this repeatedly as for the local mark ring.

Comment: then how to jump among several files?

Comment: Related to this is anything-global-mark-ring. Very important tool for programming..